# JAVA REFLECTION : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

Am using **java reflection**, Here am using object org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement, to call method called sendKeys. 
This method will accept characterSequence Array as a parameter type, so am passing characterSequence[] as parameter .  Using  classname.getMethod(sendKeys, characterSequence[]) I can get the methodname.
But when this method is innvoked in runtime  passing array of characterSequences[] as argument it throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.thbs.manager.Reflections.callSeleniumCommand(Reflections.java:115)
at com.google.manager.Testing.doTestExecution(Testing.java:105)
at com.google.manager.Testing.main(Testing.java:22)
```

Could not post the entire code,but posted the code which throws error

```
objToCallWith = org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement
cls = objToCallWith.getClass();

methodName = sendKeys
params = CharSequence[].class
// send keys method accept only CharSequence[]
myMethod = cls.getMethod(methodName, params);

// able to getMethod

args = new CharSequence[]{'a','b'}
// Here Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
myMethod.invoke(objToCallWith,args);
```

Comment: `new CharSequence[]{'a','b'}` is wrong. `'a'` is char type and thus cannot be converted to `CharSequence`. You should change to `new CharSequence[]{"a","b"}`and it will work.

Comment: new CharSequence[]{"a","b"} is also not working showing illegal argument Exception

Answer (score 3):

`myMethod.invoke(objToCallWith,args);`

should be changed to:

`myMethod.invoke(objToCallWith, new Object[]{args})`;

or

`myMethod.invoke(objToCallWith, (Object)args)`;

This is because `Method.invoke` is also accepting varargs arguments.  So, `myMethod.invoke(objToCallWith,args);` is equivalent to `myMethod.invoke(objToCallWith,"a", "b");`, which gives **two** CharSqeunce objects, rather than **one** `CharSqeuqnce[]` array object.

As you might know, `foo(CharSequence... args)` is internally compiled as `foo(CharSqeuqnce[] arg)`. So, when you call `foo("a", "b")`, it is internally `foo(new CharSequence[]{"a", "b"})`, with **one** `CharSequence[]` array object.

Comment: Error Resolved : CharSequence[]arr=CharSequence[])Array.newInstance(CharSequence.class,1);
arr[0]="ab";
returnObj = myMethod.invoke(objToCallWith,new Object[]{arr});

Answer (score -1):

```
CharSequence[]arr=CharSequence[])Array.newInstance(CharSequence.class,1);
arr[0]="ab";
returnObj = myMethod.invoke(objToCallWith,new Object[]{arr});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Otherwise, it is likely to be deleted.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.